Looking for movie based in early 20th century
Looking for a movie, it's probably 5 years old or so.
I can remember in the beginning (I believe?) it was a bank robbery in London where a tank was used to break down the walls to get in, happened at night.
The theme was sort of old, 20th century London as that was when it was based, with the protagonist looking a bit like Sherlock Holmes, and there was a lot of steampunk styling in it with old machines and inventions.
There was a scene where the bad guys had invented some sort of wireless transmitter/receiver which was connected to a bomb that would blow up some building/courthouse in London, it was next to the thames because the protagonist entered the place by going in the sewers from the Thames (I think).
Also they had some state-of-the-art steam ship/submarine thing that was capable of travelling at high speeds.
They went to Venice I believe where it was sinking or flooding or something like that due to an explosion of some sort perhaps.
It ended in some antarctic region, very snowy, when one of the characters (main enemy?) was running away in the snow and the protagonists shot him.
Any ideas what this could be?

The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen

@Oliver_C Excellent, that's it! Thanks

Thanks to @Oliver_C for answering, it was The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen. Some of my details were a little off though.

Can someone let me know what's wrong with answering my question? I got a downvote.

There is nothing wrong with answering your own question, especially as you left it for Olicer_C to make an answer, and credit him.
